# How do you stop Eclipse from inserting a certain class in Content-Assist?

Tags: eclipse, grails, jfreechart, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm using SpringSource Tool Suite (Eclipse) to program with Grails, and I'm also using JFreechart in the program.

In Grails you log by typing log.info("method worked"). Unfortunately JFrechart has a class called "Log" with Static methods like "info". This means that in STS I type `log.info` and then when I type *space* or `(` Eclipse "assists" me by importing the JFreechart Log class and changing what I've typed to `Log.info(message)`. Very irritating.

I reckon I could turn off the Eclipse option to "insert single proposals automatically", but I like this feature. Can I instruct Eclipse not to give me content assist from this particular JFreechart class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the JFreechart `Log` class to **Type Filters** via **Window > Preferences > Java > Appearance > Type Filters**:

[alt text http://www.imagebanana.com/img/aairbchy/screenshot_009.png](http://www.imagebanana.com/img/aairbchy/screenshot_009.png)